# Twitter Sentiment Analysis in R

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I'm leveraging code that I found online to do Twitter Sentiment Analysis using the AFINN sentiment dictionary, but I keep getting an error and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. My code is:

```
tweets <- data.frame(read.csv("tweets.csv"))
pacman::p_load(tm)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
dtm.control <- list(
  tolower = TRUE, 
  removePunctuation = TRUE, 
  removeNumbers = TRUE,
  stopwords = stopwords("english"),
  stemming = FALSE,
  wordLengths = c(3,"inf")
)

corpboston <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets$Tweet))
dtm.boston <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpboston, control = dtm.control)

afinn_list <- read.delim(file = "AFINN-111.txt", header = FALSE,   
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
names(afinn_list) <- c("word", "score")  
afinn_list$word <- tolower(afinn_list$word)

sentiment <- function(afinn_list, tweets) {
  tweet.sent < mat.or.vec(nrow(tweets),3)
  colnames(tweet.sent) <- c('doc','epi','total')
  word.frequency <- vector('list', nrow(tweets))
  for(f in 1:nrow(tweets))
  { tweet.sent[f, 1] <- tweets$doc[f]
    tweet.sent[f, 1] <- tweets$epi[f]
      corpboston <- Corpus(VectorSource(tweets$Tweet[f]))
      dtm.boston <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpboston, control = dtm.control)
      TermFreq <- data.frame(findFreqTerms(dtm.boston), dtm.boston$v)
      word.frequency[[f]] <- data.frame(findFreqTerms(dtm.boston), dtm.boston$v)
      sentwords <- intersect(findFreqTerms(dtm.boston), afinn_list[,1])
      sentwords.index <- match(sentwords, afinn_list[,1])
      if(length(sentwords.index) > 0)
    {
      sentwords.score <- affin_list[sentwords.index,2]
      sentwords.freq <- TermFreq[match(sentwords,TermFreq[,1]),2]
      tweet.sent[f,3] <- sum(sentwords.score*sentwords.freq)
    }
  }  
  return(tweet.sent)}
TweetSent <- data.frame(sentiment(affin_list,tweets))
```

The error that I get is:

Error in sentiment(affin_list, tweets) : object 'tweet.sent' not found

Any ideas on what I need to change or add to make the analysis work?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One of many problems could be the csv file that you are trying to read in.. try running this independently: `tweets <- data.frame(read.csv("tweets.csv"))` then `mat.or.vec(nrow(tweets),3)`. To be sure that input data is in correct shape.

Comment: Otherwise, if code is not reproducible (and we don't have your input files), posting bunch of code is kind of meaningless. Try to isolate your problem running code line by line from within function. Then try to reproduce error with minimal example with generated input (not given by file). And then share on SO.

Comment: Thank you A.Val.! I was missing a dash in the mat.or.vec line!

Comment: Wow.. I actually found a black cat in the dark room. Well, good for me, I guess. :)